# SharePoint site CSS only viewable on localhost

Tags: 2010

I have 3 web applications on a farm, 2 of them are working fine, but the other is not loading the CSS when I navigate to it using it's URL, it is loading it when I navigate to it through localhost though.

Does anyone have any information on this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should edit your post and remove your solution, then answer your own question with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue... someone migrated databases table when this new farm was created. This failed while in the process of happening, leaving the AllDocs table transferred and the AllDocStream not transferred. Meaning the application could see the css files, but they were empty. This is different to localhost as the localhost could read the local css file which was present and accounted for.

Very bizarre issue caused by databases not being moved the correct way.